# Регулярное выражение для проверки на валидность строки

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Шаблон хочу использовать для проверки на валидность строки вида:

```
a = 2
a = 2+2
а = 2 +2- 2/ 2 *2 + 2
```

Длинна строки заранее не известна, но известны разрешенные символы и их порядок.
Я написал написал вот так:

```
\s*\w+\s*\=\s*\d+[\s*\+|\-|\/|\*\d+]*
```

Но, такой шаблон захватывает и строки типа:

```
a = 2 + 
a = 2 ++
```

Чего я не понимаю, это как строгую последовательность символов сделать группой и добавить *(ноль или несколько вхождений) для нее, а так же сделать ИЛИ, которое в данном варианте почему-то не работает.

Comment: "Или" не работает так как находится в множестве символов, а по вашему примеру, думаю знак надо ловить отдельно, и поставить ему квантификатор `"?"`, и потом повторять группу при помощи квантификатора либо `"+"` либо `"*"` (зависит от того, как написать группу).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я бы посоветовал предварительно вырезать все пробелы, так как от них больше вреда, чем пользы и написать выражения для конечной строки:

```
\w+=\d+([\+\/\*\-]\d+)*
```

[image]

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!